# How to connect PyQt slot from background thread to gui thread

Tags: python, pyqt

I wish to connect up a signal in the background thread to a slot in the GUI thread in a pythonic way.

I have the following code snippet.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
class CompanyPresenter(QObject): 
    fieldChangeSignal = pyqtSignal(str, str)
    def __init__(self,model,view):
        self.model = model       # a CompanyModel 
        self.view = view         # a CompanyView
        self.fieldChangeSignal.connect(view.setField)
```

I get this error (on the connect line)

TypeError: pyqtSignal must be bound to a QObject, not 'CompanyPresenter'

But CompanyPresenter inherits from QObject so it is a QObject. What is happening?

(I want the Presenter and GUI to run in different threads eventually, but I have not got that far yet. There is no threading yet).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you forgot this:

```
def __init__(self,model,view):
    super(CompanyPresenter, self).__init__() # this!!!!!!!!!
```

add this will work.(tested)